# How do I know what interest a page is in?

Tags: stumbleupon

On StumbleUpon, how can I find out what interest a certain page is in? I took a look at the menu bar but couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on your profile click the button on a Stumble tile that says "X Likes" to see that Stumble's info page.

For example: https://www.stumbleupon.com/content/2IhS6a

You can see this is in the Christmas Interest.

While you are Stumbling on a page click on the button on the toolbar that say "X Likes" to see the info page.